# Self-signed certificates for servers accessed from external network

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate

Allright, I'm not sure how to do this properly.
So, I have an application that needs to have a certificate and trust the certificates of connecting clients in order to work. The application will generate a self-signed certificate which has information about my IP and hostname.

My client is in another network outside of my area, and it connects to my server via the Southbound Firewall's IP and a mapped port.

When it connects to my server, it probably doesn't like that my hostname isn't known, because it gives me this message.
[image: Error message]

Here is the simplified topology:

[image: Topology]

My question is, how can I make a valid certificate for my application for this external client? Could I add to it's local Hosts file that sys1 resolves to my IP?
Must I use a DNS server in the external network and add an entry there? Not sure if they have a DNS server running.
My server will be strictly for secure offline use and the client described will be the only client.

Answer (score 0):

If you let a hosts file on the client to point the name `sys1` to `171.22.150.1` and the certificate has a subject with `CN=sys1` or subject alternative name `DNS Name=sys1` it should work.